# How to check pop-up present in a page or not?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, modalpopups

How to check "popup present" in a page or not?

Suppose in my 1st run pop up present in a page, but in my second run it doesn't appear on page? I am not expecting handling popups?

Comment: Is it browser popup(Alert ) ?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Check answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392081/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-perform-if-exists-then-click-else-skip/52393829#52393829). You get code and modify for your needs

Answer (score 0):

you can try this bellow code

```
//define your main window
String mainWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle();
//handle your popup
Set<String> popup = driver.getWindowHandles();

for (String winHandle : popup) {
    if(!winHandle.equals(mainWindowHandler)) {
        //switch to popup
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        //close popup, or your action
        driver.close();
        //back to main window
        driver.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandler);
    }
}
```